# Does the Ubuntu type Desktop versus Server matter when installing one of the FTP's?

Tags: ftp

First I did

```
ps -aux | grep ftp
```

and did not find a running ftp of any kind. I'm interested in turning up an FTP service on my Ubuntu 15.04 running on my laptop.  I am aware of `ftp`, `sftp`, and `vsftpd` packages but I'm confused about which to install on my laptop.  Ultimately I wish to ftp into my laptop from another laptop to get and put files.  Which ftp package should I install on my laptop?

Answer (score 2):

From [krizna](http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/).

Secure FTP ( SFTP ) is your best bet. Here's what you need to do (just summing it up from the linked website):

1. Install openssh-server package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   ```
2. Create a new group ftpaccess for FTP users:

   ```
   sudo groupadd ftpaccess
   ```
3. Now make changes in this /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

» Find and comment the below line

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

and Add these lines at the end of the file.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

4. Restart sshd service:

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```
5. The below steps must be followed while creating Users for sftp access:

   a. Create user john with ftpaccess group and /usr/bin/nologin shell:

   ```
   sudo useradd -m john -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin

   sudo passwd john
   ```

   b. Change ownership for the home directory:

   ```
   sudo chown root /home/john
   ```

   c. Create a folder inside home directory for writing and change ownership of that folder:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/john/www

   sudo chown john:ftpaccess /home/john/www
   ```
6. Now try to connect server using SFTP ( port : 22 ) and makesure Users can upload files to www directory and cannot access other folders outside home directory.

[image: 1]

If you want use both FTP and SFTP together, please perform above steps (step 5) while creating users . For existing users, move them to ftpaccess group and create folder structure and ownership changes as below:

```
sudo usermod john -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin

sudo chown root /home/john

sudo mkdir /home/john/www

sudo chown john:ftpaccess /home/john/www
```

Comment: Just to make sure the above installation is for Ubuntu 15.04 NOT Ubuntu 14.**?  If I had staid on Ubuntu 14 there would not have been a problem.  I have a Digital Ocean Droplet that I am also working with  running 14 and have not had the problems that I am experiencing with 15.

Comment: @Cybermind - It's ought to work in Ubuntu 15.04, haven't tested it till now. Do you want me to?

Comment: oooo danger Will Robinson.  While I was waiting for responses I installed the vsftpd package.  Ran into the INVALIDARGUMENT error and looked for and found a set of config lines that would allow it to start without error.  FileZilla can "connect" but it can't talk to it times-out. PLUS the vsftpd.log file isn't created.  All of this worked without a hitch in Ubuntu 14.  Scratching head. . .

Comment: As mentioned in the website, vsftpd is not secure, that's why I mentioned sftp

Comment: are you referring to the following website? http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/  - ???

Comment: @Cybermind - AHA!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so far outside normal I have no idea what AHA! means.  Is the link I provided the website you refer to or are you referring to another "website".  I'm clearly clueless . . .  about chatting like this.

Comment: @Cybermind - Aha! = Yes!

Comment: Copy that - <smiling>

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add more than 1 user, and the process (for me) can be tedious, so I created a script to do it for me. `nano ~/add_ftp_user.sh` and paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Loosely based on https://45squared.com/setting-sftp-ubuntu-16-04

if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
    then echo "Please run as root"
    exit
fi

CONFIG_FILE="/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

echo Enter the username to create:
read USERNAME

echo Creating user ${USERNAME}...
adduser ${USERNAME}
usermod -aG www-data ${USERNAME}

echo Setting folder permissions...
mkdir -p /var/www/html/${USERNAME}
chown -R ${USERNAME}:www-data /var/www/html/${USERNAME}/

echo Editing config file ${CONFIG_FILE}...
echo ' ' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo '# Created by add_ftp_user.sh script on +%Y-%m-%d' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo Match User ${USERNAME} | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/'${USERNAME} | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'X11Forwarding no' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'AllowTcpForwarding no' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'AllowAgentForwarding no' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'ForceCommand internal-sftp' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}
echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' | tee -a ${CONFIG_FILE}

echo Restarting sshd service...
service sshd restart

echo Done
```

This will create a new user and they can login to `yourserver.com` via SFTP (which is mapped to `/var/www/html/{username}` on your server) and they can see the files at `https://www.yourserver.com/{username}`.

If you don't want other people seeing the files, modify the line so it reads: `chown -R ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} /var/www/html/${USERNAME}/`