# How to add FTP users on Ubuntu?

Tags: users, ftp

I installed an Ubuntu VPS and installed vsftpd on it. How do I add users with passwords to it that can modify the root directory?

Comment: Please refer to the answer here (from 5.a.) - http://askubuntu.com/a/712932/119531 and reply if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new system user:

```
useradd myftpuser
passwd apassword
```

If you do not want, your ftp user to access by ssh:

```
usermod -s /sbin/nologin test
```

Comment: Why did you revert the edit? This comma makes no sense in the middle of the sentence